# How to cast DataFrame to DynamicFrame in Scala

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue

```
val ruleDs = glueContext.getSource(connectionType = "dynamodb",connectionOptions= JsonOptions(Map("dynamodb.input.tableName" -> "rules"))).getDynamicFrame()
ruleDs.toDF().createOrReplaceTempView("rules")
val ruleSqlDf = glueContext.getSparkSession.sql(s"Select * from rules where id='$ruleID'")
val ruleSqlDyf = DynamicFrame(ruleSqlDf, glueContext).withName("ruleSqlDyf")
ruleDs.printSchema()
/*result 
|-- Conditions: string
|-- InstalledApps: struct
| |-- applicationPackages: set
| | |-- element: string */

ruleSqlDyf.printSchema()
/*result
|-- Conditions: null
|-- InstalledApps: struct
| |-- applicationPackages: array
| | |-- element: string */
```

How to cast DataFrame to DynamicFrame? The schema changes when i create new DynamicFrame by 'ruleDs'